# Is it possible to turn off auto-start for some (but not all) app servers deployed on Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

I want to deploy multiple versions of an app server on my local machine for development purposes (testing for compatibility, etc). I've got about 5 that I'll want to have installed at any given time, but really only need 1 or 2 of them on a day to day basis. I'd rather turn on/off the others on demand.

Originally I had problems deploying them all when I ran into memory issues, but setting `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m` took care of that. Now I've realized I don't need them all at once.

Is there a way to specify that certain applications should not auto-start?

Comment: Possible same on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386218/how-do-i-configure-tomcat-to-not-auto-start-certain-applications-on-tomcat-start

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the host-manager or the Tomcat manager for this. Also, in the `server.xml` file, you can turn off the ones you don't wanted started up by using this: `DeployOnStartup="false"`

###### Example:

```xml
<Host name="learn" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false" DeployOnStartup="false">
    <Context path="" docBase="C:/Dev/web/learn/www" />
</Host>
```

###### Reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067062/how-to-disable-specific-apps-in-tomcat

Comment: I know I can use the manager app(s) to start+stop each server, but the most important part is preventing auto-start. I'll check this out, thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't made any modifications to or duplications of the `<host>` tag. Should I? Is that preferable over using Apache VHosts and proxying each of them to a different context root?